# Trying to search for a number in a text file in Python and check if it's there

Tags: python, file-handling

I want to search for a number in a text file but whatever I enter gives me the output "The number is not in the list"

I'm a beginner by the way so this code might make some people cringe.

```py
searchfile = open("searching.txt", "r")

condition = 0 
b = input("enter a number to search ")

for line in searchfile.readlines():
    if b in line: 
        condition = True 
    else:
        condition = False         

if condition == True:
    print ("The number is in the list")
else:
    print ("The number is not in the list")

searchfile.close()
```

Comment: As soon as you find the string, you should break out of the loop.  What you have will simply tell you if the last line contains the number or not.  And by the way, it would be much more efficient for you to do `grep 123 searching.txt` and skip Python altogether.

Comment: `searchfile` is already an iterator. You don't want to use a `for` loop over `.readlines()`. Also, you should encapsulate file I/O in [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Just as mentioned in the comments, your code checks if the number is part of the last string. I would suggest the following structure:

```
def is_number_in_line(number: str, line: str) -> bool:
   return number in line

number = input("enter a number to search \n")
condition = False
with open("searching.txt") as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
   if is_number_in_line(number, line):
      condition = True
      break
if condition:
   print("The number is in the list")
else:
   print("The number is not in the list")
```

Also, note that "1" is part of the string "312 Main St", but the string does not really contain "1" as a number. You may want to modify `is_number_in_line` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
def numInfile():
    searchfile = open("searching.txt", "r") 
    b = input("enter a number to search ")
    for line in searchfile.readlines():
        if b in line:
            print ("The number is in the list")
            return
    print ("The number is not in the list")
```